# Understanding the graph of $max (|x|,|y|)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was presented with the function $max (|x|,|y|)$ which should output a maximum value of given two.... I can only suppose this one creates some body in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but how do you sketch it and what does it mean in $\mathbb{R}^3$? for that matter in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I cant really imagine it also..

Comment: Both the absolute value $|x|$ an the $\max(a,b)$ are piecewise defined functions. When studying this type of functions, divide the problem in the corresponding cases: ($x,y\geq0$, $x\geq y$), ($x,y\geq0$, $x<y$), ($x\geq0$, $y<0$, $x\geq -y$), ($x\geq0$, $y<0$, $x<-y$), ...

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy, your edit has changed the question. It is not clear that Bak1139 was wondering about the function's graph.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Has changed the question ... from what other meaning? What would be the other intention from what it was changed from?

Comment: it did change because I said I cant imagine it in R^2 also and not only in R^3

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy, you introduced the word “graph”, and it is not clear that this is what Bak1139 was asking. For example David's answer would not make sense it he had asked for the graph.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz The title is not the whole question. And all it is asked in the question is about understanding that graph.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy, that this is about the graph is your interpretation of this not very clear question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function by itself does not specify any region of $\Bbb R^2$.  If you meant $f(x,y)=constant$ then consider for example
$$\max(|x|,|y|)=1\ .$$
This can be written as
$$x=\pm1\ ,\ -1\le y\le1\qquad\hbox{or}\qquad y=\pm1\ ,\ -1\le x\le1$$
which is a square with vertices at $(\pm1,\,\pm1)$.

Answer (score 6):

It's a top-down pyramid, the faces lying in the four planes $z=x$, $z=-x$, $z=y$, $z=-y$.

Answer (score 4):

The most revealing approach would probably be to draw the set of level curves in the plane. This projects the slices through the graph by horizontal planes back down onto the domain plane, like a topographic map.

The equation of the level curve corresponding to the planar section at height $c$ is
$$\max(|x|,|y|)=c$$
This curve is a square centered at the origin with side $2c$ (for $c\geq0$). Note that the level curves are empty for $c<0$.

**Comment:** This is essentially what was suggested by @David's answer.

Comment: A downvote? Seriously?

Comment: Yes. "The most revealing approach ..." It is useful in some cases, but it is false in this problem. It is a very inconvenient approach for this problem.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy: I disagree completely. You can totally see the surface through its level curves. Perhaps you are inexperienced in using this method? But a downvote still seems harsh. "Inconvenient"? Humbug.

Comment: Of course it works. What I am contending is that is "the most revealing approach". For this problem, it is actually a very crappy method. (Talking about lack of experience... HA!)

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy: I can hardly think of a function whose level curves could be sketched more quickly. This is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: I understand, not everyone can think with the same ease. But take your time.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Is there a reason why you think that level curves are a "very crappy method" to get a picture of a surface? Contour graphs are a very useful tool when it comes to depicting maps $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Christoph The key point is "of a surface" vs "of **this** one". In every comment I used the word **this**. Don't miss it.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy I don't see any problems for this surface.

Comment: @Christoph I see no problem either. Again what I am contending is the advice that for this problem "this is the most revealing approach".

Comment: Enough on this, I think. The answer actually made a simple suggestion, not an absolute declaration. N.B. my phrasing "The most revealing approach would **probably** be...", which @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy is misquoting inflammatorially.

Comment: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1218970/26489) you will enjoy.