# how do I sketch this?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to sketch $4x^2 +y^2 = z$ but besides the fact that this is some sort of ellipse in 3d space I cant say much about it or how it should look...im also somewhat puzzled that it is not defined for points other than $(0,0)$..?

Comment: Since $4x^2+y^2\ge 0$, the surface $4x^2+y^2=z$ has $z\ge 0$. At any height $z$, the cross-section parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane is an ellipse, except that the ellipse degenerates to a point at $z=0$. Visualizing is not too bad, but sketching, as for almost any $3$-D surface, is not pleasant.

Comment: It is not defined for z<0. It is a surface in 3D, like a deformed cone with apex at (0, 0, 0). For each fixed z the cross-section parallel to the x, y plane is an ellipse, with increasing width in the x and y directions as z increases.

Answer (score 2):

This certainly won't do as a comment, but it's not really an answer. It will give you an idea at least how your sketch *should* look. Using the following block of code in `Mathematica`, I get the picture that follows:

`ContourPlot3D[4 x^2 + y^2 - z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try different positive values for $z$. That means all horizontal cross sections are ellipse.

Now try different values for $y$. If $y=0$, you get $4x^2=z$, a parabola. Different values for $x$ would also give you parabola. This means all vertical cross sections parallel to $z$ directions are parabola.

This should at least give you an idea of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^3$, since an ellipsoid is a bounded subset. However, you can draw level curves by letting $z=k$ and drawing $4x^2+y^2=c$ on the plane $z=k$. You get ellipses that become larger as $k>0$ becomes larger. Therefore your function has a graph that looks like a paraboloid in the $z$-direction with an ellipsoidal section. Here is a picture "take from below".[image]

It looks like one half of a infinite pill ;-)