# How to sketch $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : -1 \leq \text{max}\{|x|,|y|\} \leq 1 \cup 2 \leq \text{max}\{|x|,|y|\} \leq 4\}$

Tags: real-analysis

After checking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218582/understanding-the-graph-of-max-x-y) answer, I did not quite get what I was trying to understand.

I have a routine exercise which states: Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $(x,y) \rightarrow \text{max} \{|x|,|y|\}$ Sketch $f^{-1}([-1,1] \cup [2,4])$

Ok, so here's how the answer goes for this:

By definition, $f ^{-1}([-1, 1] \cup [2, 4]) = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 : -1 \leq \text{max}\{|x|,|y|\} \leq 1 \text{ or } 2 \leq \text{max}\{|x|,|y|\} \leq 4\}$. Hence, an
appropriate sketch is:
[image]

> But how do they sketch this? What are the steps for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since change of $x$ to $-x$ and $y$ to $-y$ leaves the curves invariant, they symmetric in all quadrant. So consider only the first quadrant where $x,y \ge 0$.

(1) The first figure is bounded by four lines: $ x=0, y=0, x=1$ and $y=1$. Finally it is
a square with corners $(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1),(1,-1)$. So, it is a region with all points inside it and hence it is full grey.

(2) Similarly, $max{|x|,|y|} \ge 2$ indicates all points outside the square with corners $(2,2),(-2,2),(-2,-2),(2,-2)$ and $max{|x|,|y|}\le 4$ means all points inside the square with corners $(4,4),{-4,4),(-4,-4),(4,-4)$. So the required area is the overlap of these two squares and it is  greyed..

Finally, required region is the union of these two grey regions.

Comment: so basically sketching a max(|x|,|y|) < a means the region inside the square which is centred at the origin with side of length 2a?

Comment: I have talked in terms of corners center as $(0,0)$ is understood.! Cheers.